# MACS osx will not load

Tags: macos

I re-partioned my mac drive and then when I tried to removed those partitions my MAC no longer boots.

```
diskutil list

/dev/disk1
0 GUID_partition_scheme    500GB    disk1
1 EFI EFI                  209.7MB  disk1s1
2 Apple_HFS                379.9GB disk1s2
3 Apple_HFS  Recovery HD   650MB   disk1s3
```

I have tried booting recovery mode no perform a re-install but the only disk listed is the EFI partition disk1s1.

**When running diskutil verifyDisk disk1**

```
Volume on disk1s2 has 0 bytes of trailing loader space ad it needs 134217728 bytes.
Error: 69765: Partition map needs repair because a data partition needs loader space.
```

**When running diskutil repairDisk disk1**

```
Preparing to create trailing loader space by shrinking the volume "" on disk1s2.
Creating the loader space, part 1 of 3: Verifying the file system
Problems were encountered during repair of the partition map
Error: -69763: Partition map repair failed file system check while creatig loader space for a data partition. You should repair specific partition and then try repairing partition map again.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried removing the GPT and re-adding and running test disk. All failed. In the end I earned my drive and re-installed.